# Clarification on an example of unions in C11 standard

Tags: c, unions, c11

The following example is given in the C11 standard, 6.5.2.3

> The following is not a valid fragment (because the union type is not
>   visible within function f):
>
> ```
> struct t1 { int m; };
> struct t2 { int m; };
> int f(struct t1 *p1, struct t2 *p2)
> {
>    if (p1->m < 0)
>    p2->m = -p2->m;
>    return p1->m;
> }
> int g()
> {
>    union {
>       struct t1 s1;
>       struct t2 s2;
>    } u;
>    /* ... */
>    return f(&u.s1, &u.s2);
> }
> ```

Why does it matter that the union type is visible to the function f?

In reading through the relevant section a couple times, I could not see anything in the containing section disallowing this.

Comment: The union is local to the block in which it is defined.  A union can be made global by defining it outside all functions, but before it is first used.

Comment: @ArifBurhan: I think the OP knows that the union isn't visible. The question is why that makes the code invalid.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It matters because of 6.5.2.3 paragraph 6 (emphasis added):

> One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions:
>   if a union contains several structures that share a common initial
>   sequence (see below), and if the union object currently contains one
>   of these structures, it is permitted to inspect the common initial
>   part of any of them **anywhere that a declaration of the completed type
>   of the union is visible**. Two structures share a *common initial
>   sequence* if corresponding members have compatible types (and, for
>   bit-fields, the same widths) for a sequence of one or more initial
>   members.

It's not an error that requires a diagnostic (a syntax error or constraint violation), but the behavior is undefined because the `m` members of the `struct t1` and `struct t2` objects occupy the same storage, but because `struct t1` and `struct t2` are different types the compiler is permitted to assume that they don't -- specifically that changes to `p1->m` won't affect the value of `p2->m`. The compiler could, for example, save the value of `p1->m` in a register on first access, and then not reload it from memory on the second access.

Comment: Disregard my last comment, I see your point now. The compiler's assumptions are made invalid, and so it is undefined behavior. Got it, thanks.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't make sense to me anymore. The problem seems to simply be that the pointers may point to overlapping space. This is always the case with a function like f. You might just pass the same pointer as both arguments. The function would have to behave in a way consistent with this. So it seems like the behavior may be unpredictable, but that it shouldn't be invalid. Are you saying that unpredictability qualifies as invalid?

Comment: *Unpredictability = undefined = bad;*

Comment: If t1 contained signed int and and t2 contained unsigned int AND arithmetic was carried out after the assignment the compiler would use different arithmetic operations, despite the byte sizes being the same.  The example given is slightly too simple.

Comment: @KyleStewart: You cannot pass the same pointer as both arguments of a function taking pointers to different types (with some rather specific exceptions), because accessing an object through an expression that has a type that is incompatible with the type of the object is undefined. This allows some important compiler-optimizations that would otherwise require use of `restrict`.

Comment: The issue does produce some interesting results. Consider `f` as written, and then `f` where an evaluation of `p2->m` is made following `p2->m = -p2->m;` (such as `printf (" p2->m : %d\n", p2->m);`). The result returned by `g()` is *opposite in sign* based on whether or not that type of evaluation occurs within `f`. It is almost like the operation in `f` is ignored unless the result is evaluated within `f`. I do not know what you could call that except *undefined*. Very interesting question.

Comment: @EOF `int` is compatible with `int`.  The code only accesses an `int`, not a `struct t2` or anything.

Comment: @David C. Rankin, I see your point. I meant undefined in the formal way, as used in the C standard, meaning any subsequent behavior at all is consistent with the abstract model of the standard, because it specifically disavows the situation. It seems to me that this is what is meant by "invalid", and I feel like I am lacking in understanding why that is so.

Comment: I think I finally get it, this answer answers the question, I just wasn't reading it right. The problem isn't accessing ints, it is that memory is accessed as one type (struct t1), and then as another incompatible type (struct t2), and that violates aliasing. Its the first part of the access (of structures) that's the problem, not the subsequent access of the int members.

Comment: @Kyle: Almost any code which uses structure members of non-character types violates the rules in N1570 6.5p7, since an expression `structPtr->member` is an lvalue of member type, and nothing in the Standard would allow structure objects to be accessed via lvalues of member types.  The authors of the Standard thought it sufficiently obvious that non-garbage-quality implementations should support some constructs beyond those explicitly mandated that there was no need to waste ink explicitly saying so.

Answer (score 1):

*Note:* This answer doesn't directly answer your question but I think it is relevant and is too big to go in comments.

---

I think the example in the code is actually correct.  It's true that the union common initial sequence rule doesn't apply;  but nor is there any other rule which would make this code incorrect.

The purpose of the common initial sequence rule is to guarantee the same layout of the structs. However that is not even an issue here, as the structs only contain a single `int`, and structs are not permitted to have initial padding.

Note that , as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21364467/1505939), sections in ISO/IEC documents titled *Note* or *Example* are "non-normative" which means they do not actually form a part of the specification.

---

It has been suggested that this code violates the strict aliasing rule. Here is the rule, from C11 6.5/7:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>     [...]

In the example, the object being accessed (denoted by `p2->m` or `p1->m`) have type `int`.  The lvalue expressions `p1->m` and `p2->m` have type `int`.  Since `int` is compatible with `int`, there is no violation.

It's true that `p2->m` means `(*p2).m`, however this expression does not access `*p2`. It only accesses the `m`.

---

Either of the following *would* be undefined:

```
*p1 = *(struct t1 *)p2;   // strict aliasing: struct t2 not compatible with struct t1
p2->m = p1->m++;          // object modified twice without sequence point
```

Comment: "guaranteed to have the same layout" does not mean "permitted to alias".

Comment: @o11c layout and aliasing are completely separate issues (I tried to convey that in my answer)

Comment: The way the Standard is actually written, the forms `unionPtr->member` and `structPtr->member` would have defined behavior only in cases where the member is of character type, or where the expression identifies an object of member type that is *not* part of a struct or union object.  That would make sense only if implementations are expected to recognize in at least some circumstances that a use of pointer or lvalue which is derived from a pointer or lvalue of another type should be regarded as use of the parent lvalue.  From what I can tell, gcc will recognize derivation in cases where...

Comment: ...it would facilitate optimization, or in cases where failure to do so would be indefensibly ridiculous despite being conforming.  Since the authors of the Standard openly accept the possibility that one could contrive a "conforming" implementation that is of such poor quality as to be useless, I think they expected that people seeking to write quality implementations would recognize--especially given the footnote attached to the rule--that common constructs that use type punning without aliasing should be supported when practical, whether mandated or not.

Answer (score 1):

Given the declarations:

```
union U { int x; } u,*up = &u;
struct S { int x; } s,*sp = &s;
```

the lvalues `u.x`, `up->x`, `s.x`, and `sp->x` are all of type `int`, but any access to any of those lvalues will (at least with the pointers initialized as shown) will also access the stored value of an object of type `union U` or `struct S`.  Since N1570 6.5p7 only allows objects of those types to be accessed via lvalues whose types are either character types, or other structs or unions that *contain* objects of type `union U` and `struct S`, it would not impose any requirements about the behavior of code that attempts to use any of those lvalues.

I think it's clear that the authors of the Standard intended that compilers allow objects of struct or union types to be accessed using lvalues of member type in at least some circumstances, but not necessarily that they allow arbitrary lvalues of member type to access objects of struct or union types.  There is nothing normative to differentiate the circumstances where such accesses should be allowed or disallowed, but there is a footnote to suggest that the purpose of the rule is to indicate when things may or may not alias.

If one interprets the rule as only applying in cases where lvalues are used in ways that alias seemingly-unrelated lvalues of other types, such an interpretation would define the behavior of code like:

```
struct s1 {int x; float y;};
struct s2 {int x; double y;};
union s1s2 { struct s1 v1; struct s2 v2; };

int get_x(void *p) { return ((struct s1*)p)->x; }
```

when the latter was passed a `struct s1*`, `struct s2*`, or `union s1s2*` that identifies an object of its type, or the *freshly-derived* address of either member of `union s1s2`.  In any context where an implementation would see enough to have reason to care about whether operations on the original and derived lvalues would affect each other, it would be able to see the relationship between them.

Note, however, that that such an implementation would not be required to allow for the possibility of aliasing in code like the following:

```
struct position {double px,py,pz;};
struct velocity {double vx,vy,vz;};

void update_vectors(struct position *pos, struct velocity *vel, int n)
{
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    pos[i].px += vel[i].vx;
    pos[i].py += vel[i].vy;
    pos[i].pz += vel[i].vz;
  }
}
```

even though the Common Initial Sequence guarantee would seem to allow for that.

There are many differences between the two examples, and thus many indications that a compiler could use to allow for the realistic possibility of the first code is passed a `struct s2*`, it might accessing a `struct s2`, without having to allow for the more dubious possibility that operations upon `pos[]` in the second examine might affect elements of `vel[]`.

Many implementations seeking to usefully support the Common Initial Sequence rule in useful fashion would be able to handle the first even if no `union` type were declared, and I don't know that the authors of the Standard intended that merely adding a `union` type declaration should force compilers to allow for the possibility of arbitrary aliasing among common initial sequences of members therein.  The most natural intention I can see for mentioning union types would be that compilers which are unable to perceive any of the numerous clues present in the first example could use the presence or absence of any complete union type declaration featuring two types as an indication of whether lvalues of one such type might be used to access another.

Note neither N1570 P6.5p7 nor its predecessors make any effort to describe all cases where quality implementations should behave predictably when given code that uses aggregates.  Most such cases are left as Quality of Implementation issues.  Since low-quality-but-conforming implementations are allowed to behave nonsensically for almost any reason they see fit, there was no perceived need to complicate the Standard with cases that anyone making a bona fide effort to write a quality implementation would handle whether or not it was required for conformance.

Comment: "Note, however, that that such an implementations allow for the possibility of aliasing in code like the following: ... even though the Common Initial Sequence guarantee would seem to allow for that." - is there a negation missing from there?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I think it should have said "such an implementations would not need to...".  Thanks.