# const_cast UB: clarification referefence versus object/value

Tags: c++

I know this is undefined behaviour (there's already other questions around here talking about this case):

```
int const i = 0;
int const& j = i;
const_cast<int&>(j) = 8;
```

However, I guess this isn't, right?

```
int i = 0;
int const& j = i;
const_cast<int&>(j) = 8;
```

If I'm not wrong, it's UB only to modify an **object** that is const, regardless of the qualifiers of the references you are using to refer to it. So removing a const-qualifier to a reference to an object that wasn't originally const, and then writing to it it's ok, right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're correct. That's the whole reason why you can use `const_cast` to remove the `const` qualification.

Comment: If the object being modified was not originally declared as `const`, yes, then you are ok with casting it away - but *only* if that is true.

Comment: @Barmar I think it was rather for compatibility with legacy C code I guess, where passing an object to a non-const argument, where the function doesn't actually modify it, it's a fairly common situation in old C code around (e.g., a string literal passed as a simple `char*`). I thought that was the main purpose.

Comment: String literals are the opposite of this, since the object is not declared const. If the function doesn't modify its argument it declares the argument `const char*`, and it's safe to pass the string literal -- it's *adding* `const`. This isn't an issue in C++ since the string literal is already const, so no cast is needed.

Comment: A string literal in C++ has type `char const[size]`, or am I wrong?

Comment: String literals are const. However, you can assign them to a plain `char*`. This is rather an oversight, as modifying them is still UB, but it's too late or too difficult to fix that.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Not in C++. Doing something like this: `char* str = "hi"` doesn't even compile (if you specify -std=c++something). So no, you can't do that in C++, however, you can in C (it compiles with -std=c11 for instance), and that I thought was the main reason for const_cast, that kind of interoperability.

Comment: You're right, @ABu, I confused that with C.

Comment: @ABu The standard even has an example just like yours(except that it uses pointer instead of reference). This means your 2nd snippet is well-defined as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77966097/12002570)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2nd snippet is **well-formed** because we're only prohibited in attempting to modify a const object which `i` is not. The standard even has an example that is basically the same as your's except that it uses pointer instead of reference.

From [dcl.dcl](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.type.cv-4.sentence-2).

> Any attempt to modify ([expr.ass], [expr.post.incr], [expr.pre.incr]) a const object ([basic.type.qualifier]) during its lifetime ([basic.life]) results in undefined behavior.
>
> ```
> int i = 2;
> const int* cip; 
> cip = &i;
> int* ip;
> ip = const_cast<int*>(cip); 
> *ip = 4; // defined: *ip points to i, a non-const object
> ```

The important thing to note is that the above is well-defined because `i` is non-const just like in your 2nd code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I guess this isn't, right?

Yes, your second example doesn't have undefined behavior.

> If I'm not wrong, it's UB only to modify an object that is const, regardless of the qualifiers of the references you are using to refer to it. So removing a const-qualifier to a reference to an object that wasn't originally const, and then writing to it it's ok, right?

Yes. However, when using `const_cast` like that it becomes your responsibility to make sure that the object that is referred to actually isn't `const`. In particular it would be dangerous if you get the reference from some interface where you don't control the caller.

Answer (score -3):

[Section 7.6.1.11 of Working Draft Programming Languages — C++](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const.cast#6) states that:

> [Note 2: Depending on the type of the object, a write operation through the pointer, lvalue or pointer to data member resulting from a const_cast that casts away a const-qualifier can produce undefined behavior ([dcl.type.cv]).
> — end note]

I would interpret the above to mean that it is at least dangerous to cast away the const-qualifier in the second example.

One could imagine that an optimizing compiler might assume that the target of `j` is a constant and can therefore safely be copied without needing to link the copy to its original source.  Having cast away the const-qualifier, the const_cast assignment should update the original variable.  However, a later access to `j` could legitimately access the unchanged copy (it was, after all, supposed to be constant).  I am not saying that any real implementation of a compiler actually does this.  Only that a compiler that did, may still be in conformance with the standard.

Comment: The note you quoted just says that writing through the result of a `const_cast` *can* produce UB - but if you read more you'll find that that UB only manifests if the original object was `const`. If the original object was *not* `const` then there is no UB, then the behaviour is well defined. You are dreaming up scenarios. The standard is quite clear on what is UB and what is not in this situation.

Comment: @JesperJuhl exactly which parts of the standard are you referring to?  Can you give me a paragraph number or quote the bits of the standard that you're referring to?

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const.cast

Comment: Notes are not normative, and this one talks about *"type of the object"* while intermediate references aren't objects.

Comment: @JesperJuhi which paragraph in [https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const.cast](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const.cast) supports your statement that "If the original object was not const then there is no UB, then the behaviour is well defined."

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have seen plenty of statements on this platform that treat notes as if they were gospel.  Can you point me to the paragraph in the standard that states that notes are not normative?

Comment: @Jonno https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364398/are-notes-and-examples-in-the-core-language-specification-of-the-c-standard-no

Comment: The relevant standard reference is actually in [\[dcl.type.cv\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.type.cv-4.sentence-1). It makes modifying a `const` object UB, but there is nothing else in the standard that would matter for modifying a non-`const` object through a `const` path.

Comment: @user17732522 so you seem to be saying that a compiler would be non-conforming if it made optimizations that assumed that a variable declared to be const had an unchanging value.

Comment: @Jonno Technically only object variables can be top-level `const` and for those the compiler can make that assumption. But if a compiler assumed that a lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on a reference-to-`const` will always produce the same value, even if the compiler doesn't know that the reference is bound to a `const`-qualified object, then yes, that would be non-conforming. Even if such a reference is known to be bound to a `const`-qualified object, the assumption is not generally valid, because objects can be transparently-replaced if they have dynamic storage duration, even if `const`.

Comment: And `const` subobjects of non-`const` complete objects can always be transparently-replaced.

Comment: @user17732522 About the compiler "proving" that a const-reference bound to a non-const object, but with a constant value, mmm, how can the compiler prove such a thing? It's confusing. If an object is non-const, and you have a modification after a const-cast (over an intermediate const ref bound to that non-const qualified object), then THERE'S a modification, hence it can't always produce the same value. Something doesn't add up here. If you want, instead of in this comment, talk about that situation in your answer, so you have more room for exposition clarity.

Comment: @ABu There isn't much to say about it. The point is that `const` on a reference (or type that a pointer points to) has no relevance with regard to optimization for the compiler at all. It doesn't ever give the compiler additional optimization opportunity.